# Toast Notification not being displayed in certain phones

Tags: android, android-toast

I am developing an app that includes displaying toast notification for various pieces of information. While testing on this phone: **Nokia 6.1 (Android 8)**, I realized there were no toasts being displayed.

**I am using the toast notifications the normal way as stated in Android official developer guide.**

**I double checked that my App has notification permission on.**

Then to test for any abnormality in phone side, I decided to see how the notification for "Message sent" in Gmail is implemented in this mobile. Normally, it appears as toasts but on this phone, it was appearing as snackbar.

I guess it is a custom implementation of Android. Assuming that it is custom implementation, how to accommodate any such abnormalities in my app? Should I switch to snackbar or there are any other alternatives available to deal with this issue?

I personally like the toast to display information and switching to snackbar would result in lot of potential changes in the app. Is there anything I can do to minimize the impact while supporting most of the Android phones?

I am using the following method to display toast:

```
public static void showLongToast(Context context, String message) {
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        t.show();
}
```

I debugged t.show() and the pointer went into this code in Toast.java.

```
 public void show() {
        if (mNextView == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("setView must have been called");
        }

        INotificationManager service = getService();
        String pkg = mContext.getOpPackageName();
        TN tn = mTN;
        tn.mNextView = mNextView;

        try {
            service.enqueueToast(pkg, tn, mDuration);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // Empty
        }
    }
```

Pointer went into `throw new RuntimeException("setView must have been called");`. Also, try block didn't get executed.

Comment: Are notifications from your app allowed on the Nokia? Blocking notification also blocks Toasts.

Comment: @TheWanderer **I double checked that my App has notification permission on.** Yes, notifications from my app is allowed in the Nokia.

Comment: Check the logcat in verbose mode and filter for your package name. There might be a reason why the Toast isn't showing.

Comment: @TheWanderer There is no information in logcat. I tried to debug the problematic line and found out that Android is internally throwing an exception with following content : setView must have been called. This exception is probably being called in this phone only.

Comment: can you edit that full warning into your question?

Comment: @TheWanderer Thanks for following up. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there may be an issue in how Nokia implemented Toasts.

In AOSP, this is what `makeText()` does (the public method just calls this one with a null Looper):

```
public static Toast makeText(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable Looper looper,
        @NonNull CharSequence text, @Duration int duration) {
    Toast result = new Toast(context, looper);

    LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater)
            context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflate.inflate(com.android.internal.R.layout.transient_notification, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(com.android.internal.R.id.message);
    tv.setText(text);

    result.mNextView = v;
    result.mDuration = duration;

    return result;
}
```

Notice how it sets `mNextView` to an internal View.

My theory is that Nokia broke this method somehow (maybe they removed that layout or maybe they didn't set the View at all). I'm downloading a Nokia 6.1 stock ROM to see if I can find out and I'll update this if I find anything.

In the meantime, here's a potential workaround:

```
public static void showLongToast(Context context, String message) {
    Toast t = Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    if (t.getView() == null) {
        int layoutRes = context.getResources().getIdentifier("transient_notification", "layout", "android");
        int tvRes = context.getResources().getIdentifier("message", "id", "android");
        View layout = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layoutRes, null);
        TextView textView = layout.findViewById(tvRes);

        textView.setText(message);
        t.setView(layout);
    }
    t.show();
}
```